# Why am I getting a Leverage Browser Caching error on Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: apache, caching

The page is www.catsmeowcruises.com/beta

I'm using Apache2 and have enabled both headers and expires and then restarted the server.  My .htaccess page looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On

# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

and is placed /var/www/html with the website in /var/www/html/catsmeowcruises.com/beta

However, I still get errors about Leverage Browser Caching